# Updating Google Play Services from 8.4.0 to 9.2.1 causes Gradle sync error

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, google-play-services

When I update my Google Play dependencies in my Gradle file from version 8.4.0 to 9.2.1, I get the following error:

> Error:Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:9.2.1

This was not an issue when using version 8.4.0. I tried to include it as an explicit dependency but makes no difference. The specific dependencies I’m using are:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:9.2.1'
```

I would be grateful for any pointers on why this is happening.

Comment: Update the revision in your Android SDK manager.

Comment: I updated everything in SDK manager to the latest revision but didn't fix it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try update google-services plugin in main `build.gradle` file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}
```

Comment: Gradle doesn't understand the command classpath. If I change to compile, doesn't solve the problem unfortunately.

Comment: Apologies I just realised where this is supposed to go - in the top level gradle file. I did this which fixed the original problem. Unfortunately now my project cannot find com.google.android.gms.maps.model.

Comment: Ignore the end of my comment. Seems google has got rid of a bunch of classes that used to exist which is breaking my compilation. Answer accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Add the dependency to your project-level build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'

        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
```